# how to make container scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, containers

I've got a container with a whole bunch of text in it and i want to auto-scroll to various elements in that container.  I can animate the container using jQuery to scroll a certain distance nicely, however I am having a lot of trouble determining what that distance is.

Most of the hints I see recommend using the .offset().top property to get that distance, but that isn't working in this case.  [Have a look at this jsfiddle for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/anNxU/)

**NOTE**: the fiddle targets paragraph tags that are direct children of the container, but I don't want to rely on that.  I want to be able to get the proper scroll distance for any elements, no matter how deeply nested they may be.

Comment: How will you identify the target elements? By class, id, other...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var pOffset = $("#lipsum").scrollTop();
pOffset = pOffset + $("#lipsum p.active").position().top;
```

`.scrollTop()` gives the current scroll position of the DIV, add the position of the P element to it and scrolling will be fine.

Comment: +1 for getting the answer right the first time instead of after 2 edits XD.

Comment: Thanks - works in the fiddle and in my actual project.  But I think there's a little more to it: I was surprised to find that this works even when $('.active') is nested within other elements.  For instance, in <p>The <span class='active'>quick</span> brown fox..</p> I would have expected .position().top to return the span's position within the paragraph tag (just a few pixels).  However it seems to return the spans position relative to the parent div - any idea why?

Comment: Hm. I do see that when I remove the relative positioning on the scrolling container, the positioning seems to break.  I don't see any indication in the documentation, but perhaps .position() travels up the DOM to the first positioned element?

Answer (score 4):

`.offset()` gets you the position of the element relative to the entire page.

What you need here is `.position()` that will get you the position of the element relative to the top of its containing element.

EDIT: Here it works with the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anNxU/7/)

EDIT 2: I just noticed its not going to work without adding the scroll position. You'll need to add `.scrollTop()` from the containing div. Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anNxU/14/). (It works this time)

Comment: Except that it doesn't work the second time I hit the "go" button :(

Comment: This won't work the second time, you assume an initial scroll position of 0. If you scroll manually and then press go it won't work, you need to add scrollTop() of the container to it.

Comment: @Thr4wn Yeah I noticed that. I started editing before I saw your comment XD

Comment: +1 for correct answer and working jsFiddle :) and the `+=` I always for get it works with ints