# Positioning a sap.m.list

Tags: sapui5

I'd like to create a twitter like stream out of a sap.m.list, hence when I get more data with a pulltorefresh control, I'd like to update the list with the additional rows, but should not move the list at all, and be hidden until the user scrolls the list down.
Any standard ways of doing this, or alternatively, custom CSS/JS recommended ways of doing this?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I would have expected this to work like you described in the first place... Am eager to know a solution too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to drop down to jQuery here as OpenUI5 already contains the awesome [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) library.
I've just setup a test app for you to have a look at here: https://github.com/js1972/ui5_pull_to_refresh.

Clone this; check the readme; then just run `grunt serve` to open the app in your default browser. You can use Chrome dev tools to emulate an iphone or android, etc.

I think this does what you're after - it works just like the GMail mobile app. You pull down to refresh items and at the end of the refresh your still looking at the same items but can now scroll up to see the new ones.

Will be interesting to see the performance if you have a thousand items... iScroll gives you allot of settings to play that may help (which aren't discussed in the UI5 SDK).

One thing to be careful of with browser scrolling is paint times. If the browser is not 100% done painting then iScroll can't calculate all the element dimensions it needs and you get strange results - typically just no scrolling. Sometimes you've just got to give a little time back to the browser by wrapping things in `setTimeout(scroll_stuff, 0)`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Awesome! I was absolutely unaware of this... Thanks for sharing Jason

Comment: You can check it out directly on your iphone / android here: http://js1972.github.io/ui5_pull_to_refresh/. Interestingly I've found that the pull-to-refresh control does not work when running in an iphone or android emulator from a Mac. Not even apple's own iOS emulator. However on a windows PC, Chrome can emulate it well...

Answer (score 0):

While not quite the answer I was after, looked into doing it another way, and provided you can work with automatically generated Id's that you'll need to calculate based on the row number, the following is one brute force way of doing it (I've borrowed it from another SO question and kept the animation for fun - [Referenced SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437344/how-to-make-container-scroll-to-element)):

```
var pOffset = $("#__item0-App--Main--MyList-76").position().top;
$("#App--Main--myPage-cont").animate({scrollTop: ( pOffset)}, 800);
```

Comment: Hmm - Not so fast - this works (I put it in the list's UpdateFinished event), but then doesn't allow you to scroll back to the top...